# Get averages for each day of week with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to C# and This is the first time I'm using LINQ queries. I have a Dictionary as `Dictionary<(int MeterId, DateTime TimeStamp), float>` With data as follows,

```
<(10411, 12/1/2022 12:30:00 AM), 5700>
<(10411, 13/1/2022 12:30:00 AM), 5200>
<(10412, 12/1/2022 12:30:00 AM), 200>
```

Then there's a method to add them to a list with meterId and average value for each day of week. I'm using LINQ queries to calculate the averages and get them to a list.

```
        public static List<AveragedMeter> CalculateAverageValues(Dictionary<(int MeterId, DateTime TimeStamp), float> groupedMeterValues)
        {
            var lstResult = groupedMeterValues
                .GroupBy(m => new { m.Key.MeterId, m.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek })
                .Select(g => new AveragedMeter
                {
                    MeterId = g.Key.MeterId,
                    AverageMondayValue,
                    AverageTuesdayValue,
                    AverageWednesdayValue,
                    AverageThursdayValue,
                    AverageFridayValue,
                    AverageSaturdayValue,
                    AverageSundayValue
                })
                .ToList();

            return lstResult;
        }
```

I'm not certain how to get for these average values. My AveragedMeter class is as follows,

```
    class AveragedMeter
    {
        public int MeterId { get; set; }
        public float AverageMondayValue { get; set; }
        public float AverageTuesdayValue { get; set; }
        public float AverageWednesdayValue { get; set; }
        public float AverageThursdayValue { get; set; }
        public float AverageFridayValue { get; set; }
        public float AverageSaturdayValue { get; set; }
        public float AverageSundayValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on the number of datapoints you might want to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75219480/1025555) to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted the answer is not performance optimal because it iterates all values 7 times (excluding the `GroupBy()`). I propose a solution the iterates the values only twice:

```cs
static List<AveragedMeter> CalculateAverageValues(
    Dictionary<(int MeterId, DateTime TimeStamp), float> groupedMeterValues)
    => groupedMeterValues
        .GroupBy(g => g.Key.MeterId)
        .Select(g => CalculateAverageDays(
            g.Key,
            g.ToLookup(x => x.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek, x => x.Value)))
        .ToList();

static AveragedMeter CalculateAverageDays(
    int meterId,
    ILookup<DayOfWeek, float> valuesPerDay)
    => new AveragedMeter {
        MeterId = meterId,
        AverageMondayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Monday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        AverageTuesdayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Tuesday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        AverageWednesdayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Wednesday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        AverageThursdayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Thursday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        AverageFridayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Friday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        AverageSaturdayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Saturday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        AverageSundayValue = valuesPerDay[DayOfWeek.Sunday].DefaultIfEmpty().Average()
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the data by DayOfWeek inside your select instead of grouping the dictionary, something like this:

```
static List<AveragedMeter> CalculateAverageValues(Dictionary<(int MeterId, DateTime TimeStamp), float> groupedMeterValues)
{
    var lstResult = groupedMeterValues
        .GroupBy(m => m.Key.MeterId)
        .Select(g => new AveragedMeter
        {
            MeterId = g.Key,
            AverageMondayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday).Average(n => n.Value),
            AverageTuesdayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday).Average(n => n.Value),
            AverageWednesdayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday).Average(n => n.Value),
            AverageThursdayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday).Average(n => n.Value),
            AverageFridayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday).Average(n => n.Value),
            AverageSaturdayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday).Average(n => n.Value),
            AverageSundayValue = g.Where(n => n.Key.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday).Average(n => n.Value),         
        })
        .ToList();

    return lstResult;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I tried this at first and got an exception. I was thinking maybe something wrong with my LINQ syntax. Seems like there's an issue with data.

Comment: @HARINDAVITHANA what exception are you seeing? Is it `Sequence contains no elements`? If so, some days might have no values and can't be averaged. Try `.DefaultIfEmpty().Average(n => n.Value)` instead.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank You I'll try it.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this implementation is not performance optimal. The group `g` is iterated 7 times,